# Gekko science USB miner

Tags: miner-configuration

I connect to slushpool with Gekko science USB miner at 500 Mh/s, but my workers statistitcs on slushpool say workers disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Slushpool is for mining BTC.

Attempting to mine BTC with anything less than an ASIC (minimum 2TH/s) is pointless.

You are currently running about 0.0005TH/s.
You might as well not be mining at all.